# Resource monitor missing services

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, resource-monitor

I've got an issue with resource monitor on a Windows Server 2016.
When I open it, I can see the standard processes and they seem correct.

Unfortunately the services list shows 0% cpu usage all the time and the list of services is incomplete. It looks like the list is sorted by name and cut off at 70 items. The names are only starting with A-H, so for example the windows update service is missing completely.

How would I fix this? Or is there a tool that can replace the resource monitor and provides the same info?

Comment: Resource Monitor is part of Windows. Is your Server up to date - .NET and all?   Try SysInternals Process Explorer as an alternative.  Also run DISM and SFC   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Neither dism nor sfc is finding any issues.

Comment: Try a Server 2016 Repair Install.   First screen / page in the following article covers the steps.   https://bornsql.ca/blog/repair-windows-server-2016-installation/

Comment: That link just describes how to get the issues fixed from a clean install image. But as mentioned above, dism did not find any issues, so `/restorehealth` won't attempt to do anything.

Comment: If the article posted does not work for you, then when time permits, back up and reinstall the Server.